# Каждую минуту в алерт логе сыпится ошибка ora-00600

Tags: oracle

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждую минуту в алерт логе сыпится ошибка ora-00600! С аргументами, которые ну никак не могу нагуглить.

Oracle 10.2

Comment: ORA-00600 это внутренняя ошибка БД. Вам следует обратится в службу поддержки Oracle.

Comment: Проблема в том, что поддержка не оплачена

Comment: А какую помошь вы ожидаете здесь? Оплатить за вас поддержку? На MOS хоть у вас  выход есть?

Comment: да, хочу именно чтобы вы оплатили!!!! по-моему нормальны человек понимает зачем сюда задают вопросы, чтобы получить на них возможно какой-то ответ и помощь, ввиду того что кто-то возможно сталкивался. И думаю логично, если бы у меня была оплачена поддержка, то не читал бы именно ваши бредовые комментарии

Comment: Извините, что мой комментарий показался вам бредовым. Чтобы получить ответ и помощь надо предоставить достаточно информации в вопросе. Пока её нет вообще.

Comment: тогда подскажите какую вам информацию добавить и какой именно информации не хватает? код ошибки и его аргумент есть, версия 10.2.0.5. Процесс появления ошибки неизвестен.

Comment: Вам надо исходя из alert лога определить процесс который вызвал ошибку, далее определить сессию и смотреть, что в той сессии вызвало ошибку.  _что кто-то возможно сталкивался_ - я, например, последний раз видел работающую 10g в 2012 году, если и сталкивался с чем то подобным, то сейчас врядли вспомню. Это БД продуктивная? На MOS у вас выход есть?